# Redmine installation error

Tags: bundler, redmine

I installed Redmine on my server.
When I run:

```
bundle install --without development test
```

I see an error, because I don't have PostgreSQL (and I don't use it). I want to run the bundler with parameter **--without-pg**, but I see this error:

```
root@localhost:/home/work/dev.redmine# bundle install --without-pg development test
Unknown switches '--without-pg'
```

Bundler version is 
**Bundler version 1.1.5**

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I found solution. I remove pg lib from Gemfile and everything is all right. Found answer here http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/30204

Answer (score 0):

I think that your command was wrong. You just need to remove the char - between without and pg

```
bundle install --without pg development test
```

Regards

Paul

Comment: Does not work with chilliproject (redmine fork) and bundler 1.1.4. Removing from gemfile is required.